# Sharepoint 2010 Warmup script

Tags: 2010

I'm looking for a good solid and reliable warm up application for Sharepoint 2010 that can warm up the Sharepoint site after an IIS reset.

I've tried the IIS Warm up module, but can't see any evidence that pages load quicker after it is installed.

Any other options out there?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this one?
http://nearbaseline.com.au/blog/2010/02/powershell-warmup-script-2/

I just found it, so I cannot say if its working.

Comment: I used something very similar to Alex without the additional text file for hitting specific pages. Alex's link is better.

You can achieve the same outcome as the IIS module by setting Scheduled Tasks to trigger based off events in the event log (i.e. iisReset, web app recycle).